# account transcript from states

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, state-income-tax

I can get [account transcript from IRS](https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/request-a-transcript-or-copy-of-a-prior-year-tax-return).

But can I get the same from states?

Particularly I'm interested in RI, MA and CT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to each states department of taxation website.  On the site the first search should be for *transcript*, or look under miscellaneous forms. Because what they call the form will vary from state-to-state you may have to skim all the form names.

Each state may have a limit to how far back they will go, and how much they will charge per year or per page.

Comment: okay, for RI on the site: http://www.tax.ri.gov/taxforms/personal.php I found form: Request for Copy of Income Tax Return. I just thought I could request it online.